# Handle thousands api request using cURL

Tags: api, curl, php-curl

I have around 2k of data in an array that was used for my api call and I am using curl_multi_exec to execute this. Now, max_execution_time always hits maybe even in 500 and as much as possible not going to use set_time_limit? I also tried chunking my array by passing 100 - 300 data at a time coz I thought the request will be divided and each have time limit.

Is there a better way to handle my request? I've read about putting sleep() in the loop though I'm not sure if it's a nice way. Thank You for helping.

I have this codes as reference ([this](https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/))

```
$multiCurl = array();
$result = array();

$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($ids as $i => $id) {
   $fetchURL = 'https://webkul.com&customerId='.$id;
   $multiCurl[$i] = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_URL,$fetchURL);
   curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
   curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $multiCurl[$i]);
}
$index=null;
do {
   curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
} while($index > 0);

foreach($multiCurl as $k => $ch) {
  $result[$k] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
 curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}

curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: your current do{} loop will use 100% cpu (of 1 core) until all the transfers are completed, for no good reason. if you change it to 
```for(;;){
    curl_multi_exec($mh,$still_running);
    if($still_running<=0)break;
    curl_multi_select($mh,1);
}
```
it should be just as fast and use ~1% cpu (of 1 core) instead of 100% cpu

Comment: you never close the individual curl easy handles, unless the php garbage collector has you covered, you're leaking ram by not doing `curl_close($ch);` after `curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$ch);`

Comment: Hi @hanshenrik. Thank You for your reply. I tried updating it to what you suggested and when I used the around 2k of ids at one time, data result is empty. Then when I applied the chunking of data, it still hit the maximum time limit. 

I am not really sure how it goes, but in this case should I just adjust the time limit? Well I'm running this as a background process. Sorry if I don't make sense, I'm actually new to this.

Comment: well i could guess that you just make too many simultaneous connections and get blocked by some anti-ddos system? what happens if you only load 10 at a time

Comment: it's working with 10 at time and I also with 500 at one time. It's just when I tried 1000 at one time its shows empty. And by chunking like 200 at at time, I hit the 60 maximum time limit